# How can I set the same header/footer for all worksheets, including new ones?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Every google hit for applying the same header says to highlight all sheets and set a header. How can I ensure that new sheets I add also get the same header, without alway

Answer (score 0):

As a first attempt i would use this event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
   sh.range("A1").value = "xxx"
End Sub
```

you would have to add this macro to your Workbook, not to a Worksheet, not as a Module or Class.

Anotherway might be the use of an add-in, designed for this - this would be for the purpose of having this behaviour in every workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is VBA code to copy the header and footer from the first sheet to new sheet. Insert this into `ThisWorkbook` in VBA Explorer (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and save it. It will run when you add a new sheet.

Adjust the 4th line, where it reads `Sheet1`, to be the name of your first sheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
   Dim Ws As Worksheet
   'Change "Sheet1" below to the name of sheet being copied
   Set Setup = Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
     .LeftHeader = Setup.LeftHeader
     .CenterHeader = Setup.CenterHeader
     .RightHeader = Setup.RightHeader
     .LeftFooter = Setup.LeftFooter
     .CenterFooter = Setup.CenterFooter
     .RightFooter = Setup.RightFooter
     End With
End Sub
```

If you want to run it manually, change the first line to

```
Sub CopyHeaderFooter()
```

It will then show up as a runnable macro (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>), named `CopyHeaderFooter` you can execute when you want.

Comment: I would rather not copy it to all sheets, just the new one, in case I customise the header on one sheet.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. At first, I was going to copy to all, but changed it. This code only copies to the new sheet, not all sheets.